# Is there any standard rule for considering the best result or at which stage I have to stop train the data with minimum error

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a dataset containing data 1100,  from where I have considered 75% for training, 15% testing and 15% for validation. The problem is that every time I train the network for the same training set I get very different results. Is there any standard rule for considering the best result or at which stage I have to stop train the data with minimum error.

Comment: (1) ask this at [stats.se], this site is for questions about programming (2) you have provided no details so you won't get an answer until you improve your question. Read [ask]. (3) 75% + 15% + 15% > 100% so....

Comment: Kindly please explain how you are dividing the data into the training testing and validation set ? It seems to me that you are using overlapping data (75+15+15) = 105%

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you are using a neural network, you should not have too different results between different runs on the same training set. So, first of all, check that your algorithm is working correctly using some standard benchmark problems (like iris/wisconsin from UCI repository)

Regarding when to stop the training, there are two options:
1. When the training set error falls below a threshold
2. When the validation set error starts increasing

Case (1) is clear, as the training error always decreases. For case (2) however, there is no absolute criterion, as the validation error might vary during the training. So, just plot it, to see how it behaves, and then set a threshold depending on you observations (for example, stop when its value becomes 10% larger than the minimum value it acquired during the training)